# CHROME - EXTENSION: Could not load action: noIssue.png

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on project which creates a google chrome extension. In that project, I change the icon runtime. However, in console, there is an error appears: 'Could not load action: noIssue.png'

Here is my icon set api from chrome(I am calling that in background.ts):

```
 chrome.action.setIcon({ path: './noIssue.png' })
```

I think path is also correct. Here is my dist folder:

[image: dist]

What is the problem?

(Also, I am adding icon section in my manifest file:

```
"icons": {
    "16": "icon.png",
    "48": "icon.png",
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "NS3",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
```

)

Comment: Try removing `./`. Try recreating/resaving the icon. Try renaming it to all lowercase e.g. `no-icon.png`